# Android RadioButton button not appearing in editor

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, radio-button, radio-group

Here is my activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"></include>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/choixPersonnage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/boutonGuerrier"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/personnage1"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/boutonMage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/personnage2"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is what appears in my editor:

[image]

Both button texts work, but the RadioButton buttons just do not appear, nor do they take space. They are just not there...

In all the Radio Button problems I found, no one seemed to have the same problem I do. Anyone could help me out here with this basic thing?

Comment: Probably android studio hang; try to invalidate caches/restart

Comment: This didn't work sadly :/

Answer (score 1):

I Just Copy Your Code And It's Working Fine

[image: Show Here]

Comment: Yeah I know, I think there's something wrong in my build or my theme. I'll let you know when I find the solution

Answer (score 0):

When rebuilding, I had this mistake:

```
ERROR:C:\Users\utilisateur\Desktop\APPLICATIONS MOBILES\BLOC C - INTERFACES\personnages\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.Personnages (aka uqac.dim.personnages:style/Theme.Personnages) not found.
```

So I just went in my manifest and erased the "Theme." before the "Personnages" and it worked.

Android Studio works in mysterious ways...